# Why is the viewport different from the device resolution in WKWebView?

Tags: css, webview, wkwebview

Use ipad 1024*768.

Show WebViews Using WKWebView

I want a viewport width 1024 height 768 but showing a width 1634 height 698.
The width of 1634 was confirmed using debugging. Used command window.visualViewport

I don't know why this happens, and my meta-tag is as follows.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=0">
```

my media query

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 767px) {
        // mobile
        min-width: 360px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 767px;
       
    }
    @media all and (max-device-width: 1279px) and (min-device-width: 768px) {
        // tablet
        min-width: 768px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1279px;

    }
    @media all and (min-width: 1280px) and (min-device-width: 1280px) {
        // pc
        width: 100%;

    }
```

please help me

Comment: Could you make a runnable snippet that shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I assume you don't have those comments in the actual CSS.

Comment: @AHaworth Hello, thank you for the comments. Problem solved. The cause was the initial width and height setting problem in the webview.